# Conditional formatting many cells by individual formulae

Tags: excel

I want to apply a conditional formatting (CF) rule to a group of cells to individually colour them if their individual cell values are greater than a threshold (in this case `>=5`).  To illustrate:

[image]

The top row shows how I want the bottom row to look.  For the bottom row I cannot figure out how correctly format according to cell-specific formulae.

The problem is identifying a way to specify cell-specific CF formulas in a single operation for a group of cells - as you can by pasting/dragging normal cell formulas.  I obviously don't want to have to manually specify the formula for each cell!

Grateful for assistance.

Comment: Change your rule formula to read `=B3>=5`. Your current formula uses the `$` modifier, which forces the rule to always use cell `B3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the rows or columns or range that you want to conditional format,

Enter the below formula in the formula bar in conditional format and choose a fill color,

```
=AND(A1>=5,ISNUMBER(A1))
```

[image]

If you are starting in row3, change the `A1` to `A3`. The `$` that you have in the formula makes it absolute. It should be relative.

Comment: For some reason this works now. I must've been doing something wrong.

Comment: The `$` created trouble for you. Now it should work. Please upvote if you found this useful

Answer (score 0):

You just select all required cells to format. Then go to conditional formatting.

Check what is the cell shown just before the formula bar (the single cell that represents the selected range, also called default cell) and use that cell in your formula without absolute reference. like B3>=5 or R3>=5